# How should I add buttons to the right on my rows in HTML?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: s]

I have the buttons on both rows being added dynamically just as another `<td>` after each of the table data and it just gets added as something outside of the table. I'm guessing this is pretty hack-ish, and it doesn't even work for the first table. What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do? These tables are just tables with table rows and table data.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you try using Bootstrap Quick floats classes? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats

Comment: @marcelo2605 no, but would you suggest it?

Comment: Yes, try it and tell me if you solve your problem